# How do I make the sidebar fit the window and the google map to fit the rest of the screen?

Tags: html, css, google-maps-api-3

Here is a link to the site I am working on: http://thoughtfi.com/practiceIMR3.html

I am trying to get the sidebar to extend the length of the browser window and have a width of about 200px and then have the map fill the rest of the browser window. I have spent a good amount of time messing with the css to get it to work but without any luck. When I have the css for the map div set to a persent of the screen, it cuts out most of the map. When I have the length of the scroller set to 100% it includes all the information and does not have a separate scroll that just extends the length of the page.

Here is what my css currently looks like:

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body, #map_canvas {
    width:   800px;
    height:  600px;
}
#sidebar {
    width:200px;
    height:600px;
    overflow:auto;
}
</style>
```

and here is the important parts of my body:

```
<body onload="initialize_page()" style = "height:100%; margin:0">
    <button onclick="hide_markers_kml();">hide</button>
    <button onclick="unhide_markers_kml();">unhide</button>

    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                  <div id="sidebar"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `TABLE` for layout, try using absolute positioning. For example, see my fiddle, [A simple 100% layout](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/Bn5Lt/3/). The trick is to absolutely position the sidebar and content, specifying the `left`, `top`, `right`, or `bottom` properties, and letting the browser automatically calculate width and height where needed.

In the demo, I have the sidebar set to `left: 0; width: 200px;` and the content set to `left: 200px; right: 0;`. This creates a 200px wide sidebar area, and the browser calculates the remaining width of the page for the content area.

Comment: hmm, there are two bottons at the top that get covered in text and when I scroll it's not just the list, it's the whole webpage. Any ideas on how to fix? http://thoughtfi.com/practiceIMR4.html

Comment: use [overflow: auto for your sidebar](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/thoughtfi_com_practiceIMR4.html)

Comment: Yep, what @geocodezip said. Also, you'll need to specify `top: 2em; bottom: 0;` and get rid of the `height` property (the height will be automatically calculated from the `top` and `bottom` properties). So all told, `#sidebar { position: absolute; right: 0; width: 200px; top: 2em; bottom: 0; overflow: auto; }`. (btw, the `top: 2em;` is to make space for the buttons… `top: 0;` would also work)

Comment: Also, in case you ever want to put this inside another website or a smaller container, just wrap the contents of the `BODY` tag in a `DIV` instead, and give that `DIV` the `position: relative;` CSS property. Boom, done.